# Simplify a nested loop structure in C++

Tags: c++

I found a nested loop structure in a program, which looks in a simplified version like the following. 
The variable `empty_count` is estimated before the outer loop is reached. Then the loop tries to do something to decrement `empty_count`. However, `empty_count` may never approach zero, so the programmer thought the following: "Just run the inner loop at least one time until `empty_count`
 does not change anymore, and break the outer loop".

I struggle a bit here, because I want in the best case just one for loop which can be used with OpenMP. Not sure whether this is possible.

```
// empty_count = some_value
size_t last_count = 0;              // starting value is 0
while (last_count != empty_count)   // count as long as the counter changes in the inner loop
{
    last_count = empty_count;       // update the counter for the break condition
    for (size_t id = 0; id < array.size(); id++)
    {
        if(some_condition) continue;

        int foo = some_function();
        switch (foo) {
        case 0:
            continue;
        case 1:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        };

        empty_count--; // maybe never reached :/
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by 'simplify'? I think this loop just doesn't work the way you've described right now. The inner loop is not going to quit when empty_count doesn't change anymore - instead it is going to iterate through the whole array every time, regardless of it reaching the empty_count or not.

Comment: Yes, but the outer

Comment: The outer one is also going to stop after one execution only, and you want to stop it after two executions if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this code :

```
 int foo = some_function();
    switch (foo) {
    case 0:
        continue;
    case 1:
        break;
    default:
        break;
 };
```

with

```
if (some_function() == 0) continue;
```

Comment: No you can't!  The `break` in the switch will break out of the switch.  A break in the `if` will break out of the loop!

Comment: if foo == 0, we should continue for loop which is missing in this piece of optimised code. Also as @MartinBonner said, break is for switch and not for for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `last_count` must be the same as `empty_count` is actually just a flag, so the counts can be replaced by a flag. You may need to handle the case where `some_value` is 0 before the loop, which will cause the loop to not be run in the original code.

Next is the easiest change to make the code slightly easier without changing functionality.  Mind you that the switch when being simplified for this example is actually rather useless so I replaced it too.

```
bool nextloopFlag = true;             // starting value is 0
while (nextloopFlag)   // count as long as the counter changes in the inner loop
{
    nextloopFlag = false;
    for (size_t id = 0; id < array.size(); id++)
    {
        if (some_condition) continue;

        if (some_function() == 0) continue;

        nextloopFlag = true;
    }
}
```

To avoid the flag, sometimes a goto is used to jump out of the nested loops.  There is some debate whether this is better.  In this case, the goto would jump immediately out of the inner loop, so it would not be the same as the original code.

I hope this helps with ultimately bringing it back to 1 loop.

Answer (score 1):

The body of the loop:

```
        if(some_condition) continue;

        int foo = some_function();
        switch (foo) {
        case 0:
            continue;
        case 1:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        };
        empty_count--; // maybe never reached :/
```

Can be replaced with:

```
        if(some_condition || some_function() == 0)
           // Do nothing
        else
           empty_count--; // may never be reached :/
```

Without showing us more details of condition and function, it is not possible to show how to turn this into a single loop.

Comment: I was focusing on removing the counters, so I kept the `continue`s.  This looks actually cleaner.

Comment: And one could combine the two by replacing `empty_count--` with `nextLoopFlag = true` (except I would rename it as `keepGoing = true`)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
void update(size_t& id, bool& flag, size_t sz)
{
    if (++id == sz && flag)
    {
        id = 0;  // repeat the loop
        flag = false;
    }
}

bool flag = false;
for (size_t id = 0; id < array.size(); update(id, flag, array.size()))
{
    if (some_condition || !some_function()) continue;
    flag = true;
}
```

(I didn't test this, but something along those lines to simplify to a single loop)

And as mentioned in other answers, in this case you might not even need the continue statements:

```
bool flag = false;
for (size_t id = 0; id < array.size(); update(id, flag, array.size()))
{
    flag = flag || !(some_condition || !some_function());
}
```

Comment: Clever, but hackish.  It actually hides the outer loop by resetting the index (comment: repeat the loop), which I'm not particularly fond of.

Comment: Yes, true, that is the idea behind (to reset id to 0 if the loop needs to be repeated). The goal was to use a single loop, however, I'm not sure if this would actually work well with OpenMP :)